# Generating array with random integers C

Tags: c, arrays, random, srand

so I am trying to fill an array with random integers.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    srand(time(NULL));
    array[i]=rand()%30; }`
```

Here is my code so far. I am currently getting the same random number twice. Would like to know if there is a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rand()` usually uses a PRNG, which uses the seed to generate the random number. `srand ( time(NULL) );` is used to seed the pseudo-random number generator.

Currently, the time granularity of `time()` is 1 second, so if you seed the PNRG with the same value [`time(NULL);`] multiple time within the granularity period, call will to `rand()` generate the same random number.

Move the `srand(time(NULL)` outside the loop.

Comment: Granularity of `time()` is unspecified by ISO/IEC 9899 (The C Programming Language). The granularity in seconds is a specification made by POSIX.1.

Answer (score 2):

You seed the PRNG multiple times in the loop. It should be done only once.

By calling `srand` in the loop you *reset* the seed. And if you pass the same value to `srand` then the next call to `rand` will generate the exact same value.

Comment: Ninja'd, and better explained. ;-)